# OpenCV program x64 with VS

Tags: opencv, 64-bit

I want load a program demo of OpenCV using build files for x64, but always return me null, the function imread(...):

I use OpenCV 247 and only linker opencv_core247d.lib, opencv_highgui247d.lib

I use the OpenCV for Windows

```
>include: ...\opencv\build\include
>lib: ...\opencv\build\x64\vc10\lib
>bin: ...\opencv\build\x64\vc10\bin

#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
    if( argc != 2)
    {
     cout <<" Usage: display_image ImageToLoadAndDisplay" << endl;
     return -1;
    }

    Mat image;
    image = imread(argv[1], CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);   // Read the file

    if(! image.data )                              // Check for invalid input
    {
        cout <<  "Could not open or find the image" << std::endl ;
        return -1;
    }

    namedWindow( "Display window", WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );// Create a window for display.
    imshow( "Display window", image );                   // Show our image inside it.

    waitKey(0);                                          // Wait for a keystroke in the window
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are passing the image path with a single backslash (\) then opencv seems not to recognize the path.

Ex: *Drive:\folder1\folder2\imagename.extension*

You might want to try with double backslash (\\) or forward slash (/).
Ex:

*Drive:\\folder1\\folder2\\imagename.extension*

OR

*Drive:/folder1/folder2/imagename.extension*

Comment: I use "\\" and not working.

I have found that the problem is in the function of load image. I use now:

IplImage* ipl_img = cvLoadImage(src.c_str(), CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);

image = Mat(ipl_img,true);

cvSaveImage(dst.c_str(), &(IplImage(image)));


anyway, thanks.